# How can I run jsp file in vscode?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I have Tomcat server and tomcat server extension for vscode is ready(it may not be essential).
I want to check my web made by jsp.
How I can check my jsp file on web using vscode?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your JSP and Java code in VS Code but to see your code you would start tomcat and view your pages with a web browser.

1. using maven command run 'mvn install' in your project root same location as pom file -> a war of your project is created
2. copy that created war file into your tomcat "webapps" directory
3. start tomcat
4. to see more changes repeat ( you don't have to restart tomcat it should pick up the war is new)